# How to load gridview from data table without replacing previous data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a textbox txtId and a grid view, the grid view displays data according to id provided.It is fine but whenever I provide Id for second time the grid is loaded with new data and my previous id data is gone from gidview.

I want something like this:

[image]

Whenever I enter Idsecond time previous data is gone I want new data with previous like above picture.

Below is my grid view where I have used eval to bind grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVProduct" CssClass="table table-hover" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ItemName") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CP">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCP" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CostPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And this is how I load grid on button click:

```
   protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int itemIds = Convert.ToInt32(txtPId.Text);
            int qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
            if (txtPId.Text!=String.Empty || txtQty.Text != String.Empty)
            { 
                DataTable dt = bllProduct.GetProductById(itemIds);
                if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
                {
                    GVProduct.DataSource = dt;
                    GVProduct.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `GetProductById(itemIds)` is returning only one record please check your select query in `GetProductById` method.